# flyspell doesn't load with LaTeX file in emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, flyspell

Following [this web page](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Manuel.Serrano/flyspell/flyspell.html), I have edited my ~/.emacs file and added the line:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

However, flyspell doesn't start with LaTeX files. Why is that so?

Comment: Please accept answers to your many questions. Below you say "Thanks" but haven't up-voted or accepted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs is case-sensitive; the hook should be written as `latex-mode-hook`.  Try this:

```
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

Comment: So that flyspell.el web page is relevany to reftex or something, thanks

Answer (score 5):

I could not make this work:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)   or
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

But then I found this:

`(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)`

-and it is working.

Comment: This solved the problem for me too; it seems that `'latex-mode-hook` works for some and '`LaTeX-mode-hook` for others. I was mistakenly using `'latex-mode-hook` with `'turn-on-flyspell`